# How to fix pytube error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pytube

I am making a app where I can put the link in one entry box and then put the output directory in another entry box. I am using tkinter to shape the app and I am using `pytube` to download the video. When I am trying to download the video by pressing the video I am doing these things:

1. Get the strings from the entry boxes
2. Then get the video by using `vid = YouTube(link)` if that doesn't work then `print("Connection Error or Video doesn't exist")`
3. Then get the max resolution for download using `vid_res = vid.streams.get_highest_resolution()`
4. Finnally I do `vid.streams.filter(res=vid_res).first().download(dir)` to download the video and if that doesn't work do:

```
except IndexError as e:
            print(e)
```

And then when I click the button it loads for a while the give me the error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download'

The whole error message says:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Coding\Python\YTDownloader\YTDownloader.py", line 40, in <lambda>
    activeforeground="#ffffff", text="Dowload Video", font=('Courier', 20), command=lambda: Download.dowload_vid(temp_link, temp_dir))
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Coding\Python\YTDownloader\Download.py", line 15, in dowload_vid
    vid.streams.filter(res=vid_res).first().download(dir)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download'
```

Here is the code:

```
from pytube import YouTube

def dowload_vid(l, d):
    link = l.get()
    dir = d.get()

    try:
        vid = YouTube(link)
    except:
        print("Connection Error or Video doesn't exist")

    vid_res = vid.streams.get_highest_resolution()

    try:
        vid.streams.filter(res=vid_res).first().download(dir)
    except IndexError as e:
        print(e)
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: please provide your full code as code block. makes the life easier for everyone

Comment: Oh yea sorry I knew I was forgetting something

Comment: I added the code sorry for not adding it earlier

Comment: The first thing to do is verify that `vid.streams.filter(res=vid_res)` returns what you expect. Then, verify that `vid.streams.filter(res=vid_res).first()` returns what you expect. One or both of those is not what you're assuming they are.

Comment: Have you tried updating `pytube`? I recommend to uninstall and install `pytube` back.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes I did try what you said and I found that `vid.streams.filter(res=vid_res)` returns `<Stream: itag="22" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="24fps" vcodec="avc1.64001F" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">` but when I try `vid.streams.filter(res=vid_res).first()` it returns `None`. So how can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know. I've never used that library. At a minimum, your code needs to check whether it returns `None` or not before trying to call `.first()` on it.